# How can i go App starting page in ios

Tags: ios, swift

I was trying to build a app. which have many page and every page have a navigation item called Home.

when it click it will go home page, mean's start page. I don't want to instantiateViewController. I want fist initialise page will come. how I can do this. I don't want to dismiss page. because it's take many click to go home page

I was try this

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {});  
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true);
```

[image: initial view controller]

Comment: Are you using a NavigationController?

Comment: i have NavigationController for all page without rootview controller

Comment: That's not possible. The first controller in the NavigationController is the root. So just popToRootController should so the job

Comment: i mean go to initial view controller.

Comment: did you got it??

Comment: I Think you have try this  navigationController?.popToViewController((navigationController?.viewControllers[1])!, animated: true)

Comment: Actually given image is my initial view which background is clear and after that all of my view controller have navigationcontroller. my initial viewis  on the top of second page. for my initial background cleare color my second view controller is showing and working. when i go to other page all page will  hide. after clicking my navigation item name home it will go to initial page. is it possible ??

Comment: @SporshiyaIslam did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Pops all the view controllers on the stack except the root view controller and updates the display.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3+:** You can relaunch app by using below line of code.

```
func moveToRootViewController(){
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
    window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UINavigationController` method `popToRootViewController(animated:)` for your purpose. Set your Home as root of your Navigation Controller. You can push required View Controllers using same Navigation Controller. Whenever you press Home button inside any page just pop all View Controller and display Root View Controller using above method. 
You can use it as

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

call this method on home button click in every pageof app.

From Apple documentation :

> popToRootViewController(animated:) Pops all the view controllers on
>   the stack except the root view controller and updates the display.